# Delphi: PByte в строку и обратно

Tags: delphi

Delphi Rad 10.3 Com.
Вот есть такие функции (для string аналогично).

```
Function PByte2StrA(Const Buf:Pbyte):AnsiString;
begin
Result:='';if SizeOf(buf)=0 then exit;Result:=AnsiString(buf);
end;

Function Str2PByte(Const Str:AnsiString):PByte;
begin
if str='' then exit;Result:=pbyte(str);
end;
```

И они вроде как работают. Это корректно или есть способ лучше?

- [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314961/delphi-pbyte-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 1):

`SetString`

Для второго зачем отдельная функция?

Comment: >> Для второго зачем отдельная функция? Чтобы в других модулях и dll юзать. Да не важно, теоретический больше вопрос. В SetString(StrA,buf,size); - ругается на несоответствие типов у buf (pchar vs pbyte)

Comment: `Чтобы в других модулях и dll юзать` это не объясняет, зачем нужна функция вместо приведения типа. Вы собрались строки в DLL использовать? `несоответствие типов` - просто приведите buf к типу PChar

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да это работает, вы уверенны, что эти решение верные и единственно надежные? >> Вы собрались строки в DLL использовать? Да, я уже работал с этим, знаю про эту проблему. Если все в одной среде и юзать общий модуль памяти, то сносно. А так, да, если такие dll юзать из др. языков, то только указатели или буферы байтовые работают. Просто боюсь вот с таким столкнуться: http://delphimaster.net/view/15-1242063452

Comment: Это самые простые решения, для использования других нужны особые причины.