# Delphi: PByte и память

Tags: delphi

Delphi Rad 10.3 Com. Есть вот такой простой код:

```
...
Const StrA:ansistring='Test12345'; // 9 byte
Var buf:Pbyte; size:integer;
begin
size:=Length(StrA)*SizeOf(StrA[1]); // = 9
Getmem(buf,size); // 1 
buf:=pbyte(StrA); // 2 
FreeMem(buf);     // 3
end;
...
```

При выполнении получаем ошибку "Invalid pointer operation".

Варианты:

- если убрать строку 2 или 3, то ошибки нет
- если убрать строки 1,3 - ошибки нет (но подозреваю, что будет утечка памяти)
- вместо строки 2 пробовал buf:=pointer(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stra)); - ошибка есть
- вместо Getmem+Free mem пробовал конструкцию New+Dispose и Finalize - ошибка есть

Подозреваю, что проблема в [строке 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314955/delphi-pbyte-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Вопрос: Что не так в коде и откуда эта ошибка? Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2):

```
Getmem(buf,size);
```

выделяет память, buf на неё указывает

```
buf:=pbyte(StrA);
```

а тут указатель переназначается на адрес константной строки, выделенная ранее память "утекает"

```
FreeMem(buf);
```

Кто позволит фримему освободить память, выделенную программой под  константы?

Наверное, вы подразумевали какую-то логику. Вот и опишите задачу, а не этот рандомный набор команд

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ок, сделал StrA переменной, с присвоением значения в начале блока: strA:='Test12345'; Ошибка не пропала :( + >> Вот и опишите задачу.  Задача получить рабочий код в примере выше :) 1. Есть некая строка.; 2. Надо ее запихать в буфер типа pbyte (так понимаю, для этого нужно выделить память и корректно провести перенос); 3. Что-то делаем с буфером (куда-то его пишем например), без изменения; 4. Корректно завершить процедуру (освободить память под буфер?), чтобы при повторном множественном ее вызове не было утечек памяти.

Comment: В данном случае (`без изменения`) просто приводите тип к pbyte, раз уж он требуется. Выполняете работу. Потом строка освобождается автоматически, или при необходимости освобождаете её вручную (setlength или nil). В таком случае никаких утечек не будет.

Comment: Если данные из строки нужны именно в новом куске памяти - выделяете память любым способом. Копируете данные с помощью move. Поработали с буфером. Освободили буфер (способом, комплементарным к методу выделения памяти)

Comment: ++ пока писал, отв. выше. Ранее: К сожалению, у меня маленький скил в теме указателей и работы с памятью  :( только отдаленно представляю как это работает + pbyte недавно появился (относительно). Если можно, посоветуйте, как сделать правильно. Я правильно понимаю, что объявление переменной типа pbyte требует выделение\освобождение памяти для нее при работе? Напр. при чтении файла: .. var f:tfilestream; x,len:int64;buf:pByte;...begin GetMem(buf,10); F:=TFileStream.Create('my.txt',fmOpenRead);len:=F.Size; repeat x:=f.Read(buf^,10); .. until x>0;  F.Free;Freemem(buf);.. это работает норм.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, попробую, отпишу позже.

Comment: Если pbyte указывает на уже выделенную память, то ещё раз выделять не нужно

Comment: Это ясно, поправил комент с примером чтения файла процедуры.

Comment: Пример с чтением правильный. Потребная память выделяется только с помощью buf, только buf указывает на данный адрес, он отвечает за всё. В коде в вопросе память уже есть, новой выделять не нужно, если работать с ней только на чтение. Если нужно работать на запись - делаете, как я описал в комменте " в новом куске памяти "